# Does each object allocate memory for constants?

Tags: c#, vb.net, memory, memory-management

In my code design, I've included a lot of constants. When a new object is created, is memory allocated for that object's constants, or is it stored permanently in a single instance, like a static variable is? In terms of memory storage, where exactly do static items end up?

In other words, if I define 100 objects, will there be 100 copies of the same constant value?

If they are defined in static memory (wherever that is), and I would expect that they are, does accessing them require the computer to switch memory pages? Is there a performance hit for constantly accessing constants instead of variables?

Thanks

Ares

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Constants have no storage location at runtime.  All access to constant identifiers results in the literal value of that constant replacing the identifier when the code is compiled.

Comment: No, **const string literals will have object reference to an interned String object**. This is called **string interning** and applied by CLR to improve the performance and reduce the memory space required to hold all those literals which have identical character sequences.

Comment: @Mert But the constant identifier is not what is holding onto any of that data.  The semantics are identical to having simply embedded the actual string literals all throughout the code.  Yes, if interning is enabled this happens to result in the strings being in an intern pool and all access to those literals in code is instead using a hard coded reference to that string in the pool.  From the point of view of `const` semantics this is all irrelevant.  None of that memory represents storage of that const identifier.

Comment: if you consider the question asked your answer can be interpreted wrong because if all strings are pushed with **ldstr** command, then you will have a big performance hit and memory consumption. Think about a program which accesses a const string millions of times, that would be a problem if we load the literal from metadata each time, right?

Comment: @Mert And if you disable string interning, that's exactly what happens.  You're referring to a feature that's separate from the concept of const-ness.  Accessing a const string millions of times is no different from simply embedding the same string literal in your program millions of times.

Comment: To answer the question "In other words, if I define 100 objects, will there be 100 copies of the same constant value?" if interning is on(by default), then an object will be referenced. If not, then there will be a performance hit and your code will get bigger. I think that is a better explanation of what is asked.

Comment: @Mert But that's a very different question from what's asked here.  Discussing a number of entirely separate question serves to confuse the answering of this question, which is very straightforward.  There's always some other piece of tangentially related information that you *could* include.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173119.aspx):

> In fact, when the compiler encounters a constant identifier in C# source code..., it substitutes the literal value directly into the intermediate language (IL) code that it produces.

Therefore, using a constant, like this:

```
const int myConst = 5;
int x = myConst;
```

Is literally (pardon the pun) no different than the following code:

```
int x = 5;
```

The compiler will generate the same output either way.  When the assembly is run, the value is stored in the stack (the local memory of the executing method).  No look up, memory page switching, memory-heap access, or anything else is necessary.